# Is it possible to initialize a Metal array texture all at once?

Tags: macos, textures, metal

An **array texture** (not to be confused with **texture array**) in Metal can be used to pass a **non compile time constant number** of textures of the **same dimensions** to the GPU at the same time. So far, the only way I know of to create these is with a custom `MTLTextureDescriptor` and then copying the data manually. Currently I use a for loop to copy one slice at a time:

```
let descriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
descriptor.width = 32
descriptor.height = 32
descriptor.mipmapLevelCount = 5
descriptor.storageMode = .private
descriptor.textureType = .type2DArray
descriptor.pixelFormat = .rgba8Unorm
descriptor.arrayLength = NUM_TEXTURES
if let texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: descriptor) {
    for i in 0..<NUM_TEXTURES {
        commandEncoder.copy(from: sharedBufferWithTextureData, sourceOffset: i<<4096, sourceBytesPerRow: 128, sourceBytesPerImage: 4096, to: texture, destinationSlice: i, destinationLevel: 0, destinationOrigin: MTLOrigin())
    }
}
commandEncoder.generateMipmaps(for: texture)
```

However, is there a way to copy all the slices at once? [OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture) seems to provide a way to do this, but how can I do this in Metal? What is the best way to create a `MTLTexture` object where `textureType` is `type2DArray` and `storageMode` is `private` then populate the texture data?

Note: The `storageMode` is `private` because `MTLTexture` does not support `shared`, and `managed` results in separate copies of the data, which is unnecessary memory usage.

Comment: There's no way to populate more than one slice in single blit command. You need a blit command for each slice (element) of the array textures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to populate more than one slice in single blit command, as there is no [`copy()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlblitcommandencoder/1400752-copy) method that can handle more than one slice at a time.

It is also not possible to create a buffer with the slice data and create a texture that shares the memory of the buffer using [`MTLBuffer.makeTexture()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlbuffer/1613852-maketexture) as this function explicitly disallows use with array textures.

The only way to copy 'multiple' textures worth of texture data at once is to combine multiple textures into a single one, for example, by using a [texture atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas).

Comment: If you were to use an atlas, you need to be super careful about how you sample it at the boundaries between the slices of an atlas. Otherwise you will get artifacts

Comment: @JustSomeGuy True. Probably better to just use an array texture anyway.